# I want to make a "hole" on few line on illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm having trouble while making a project, I want to create this :

[image: this]

But for now, it's just lines with a circle to fake the transparency, I try using pathfinder but I didn't find how to do it.

I find a solution by making it a pattern but I prefer having an object I can edit if I need.

Thank you in advance to the nice people who will answer and sorry for my broken english.

Answer (score 1):

There are many option available. 
May be you can use Shape builder Tool (shift + M)to do this:

Here's the Example:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to try a couple things.

1.) select all and then hit shift m (on a mac, I dunno on a pc but its for the "shape builder tool).

while holding the option key, hover over individual points in the shape/ design. The strokes that appear in red are whole segments you can delete. Just click while holding option to delete.

If that doesn't work

2.) Any path can in Illustrator can be converted to a shape and built on to or knocked out of other shapes. Now with the shape selected navigate to object > path > outline stroke to make the stroke an object.

Now with both objects selected, choose the 'minus front' option from the pathfinder panel to knock out the front shape. This can be particularly useful when designing logos where you want to show through to the background that the logo is overlaid onto.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Select all lines that are overlapping with the circle. Then go to: `object > expand...` select both *fill* and *stroke* and click 'ok'. Now select all the converted lines and go to `object > compound path > make`. Finally select all the lines and the circle and hit `minus front` on the pathfinder panel.

You can omit the first step if the "lines" are already rectangular paths with fill rather than simple lines with stroke.